# How can I separate these absolutely positioned table elements?

Tags: html, css

If I use the following technique. child 3 gets sucked into parent 2. 
Child 3 is actually a `<table>`, not a `<div>`. but it is still positioned absolute.

So basically I want to have 1 parent div with children in it, then have another parent div below it with children in it.

```css
#parent1 {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-size: 5px;
}
#child1 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-size: 5px;
}
#child2 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-size: 5px;
}
.child3 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-size: 5px;
}
#parent2 {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-size: 5px;
}
#child4 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-size: 5px;
}
#child5 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-size: 5px;
}
.child6 {
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2"></div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>

<div id="parent2">
  <div id="child4"></div>
  <div id="child5"></div>
  <div id="child6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use a class selector for an ID for `child3`?

Comment: There's no attribute `border-size` - try `border-width` instead.

Comment: xufox... thats actually a table. not a div. is that whats throwing it off??

Comment: singularity. i wont be keeping the borders. they are just there for reference so i can see the movement of the divs clearly. thanks anyway

Comment: if child3 is a class (hence the dot . in .child3) you need to change to `<div class="child3"></div>`

Comment: @user2585548 No, in CSS `.child3` selects an element with the _`class`_ `child3`, but `#child3` selects an element with the _`id`_ `child3`. Also `id="parent 1"` and `id="parent 2"` aren’t valid IDs and they won’t get selected by `#parent1` and `#parent2`.

Comment: ok i see that the id's have spaces. its right in the css. i just typed them wrong on here

Answer (score 0):

update css:

```
#parent1, #parent2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: blue;
    border-width: 5px;
}
```

because the children are absolutely positioned, the block level parents dont count their height. so you need to set `display:inline-block` + `width:100%` on both parents, or set explicit width/height.

Answer (score 0):

When child nodes are absolutely positioned, the dimensions of them are ignored when rendering the parent node. Some JS will be needed to set the correct width/height in this case.

> So basically I want to have 1 parent div with children in it, then
>   have another parent div below it with children in it.

Without JS, I would use the following to layout the blocks. However, it really depends on your design.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
.parent:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
.child1 {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.child2 {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}
.child3 {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child2">child2</div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child4</div>
  <div class="child2">child5</div>
  <div class="child3">child6</div>
</div>
```